# Ubuntu install doesn't recognize SSD but Windows 7 does

Tags: boot, windows, ssd, 15.10

I tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 (amd64) on my workstation machine onto a Kingston V300 SSD drive without success.

Motherboard is: MSI K9ND Speedster2

I cannot find AHCI option in the BIOS only RAID.

BIOS is able to see the SSD.

Windows 7 works and boots very well and fast, but when I try to install Ubuntu neither the disk manager nor the fdisk, or gparted can see the SSD device.

Whats wrong? I have been searching for a couple hours on google but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that this is a problem with your hardware by trying find the Kingston drive with sysRescueCD.  If it can find it, then try a different version of Ubuntu